# Python cannot load project module Django Mod_WSGI

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, linux, apache

I am trying to deploy a test Django project onto an Apache2 server running under Debian 10.
Django is running in a virtual environment under Python 3.7.
After about 3 days of going in circles, I have got something to load upon connecting to the Apache server, but now I get the following Python error:

My Django project is called myproject (how creative), and has 3 apps underneath it.

I originally had it running in a virtual environment created using Pipenv, which was located in /home/dj/, and I entered into that virtual environment using 'pipenv shell' in that folder.

I then had issues with the Python executable path and libraries, and discovered on day 2 that pipenv doesn't use shared libraries and is a lot more difficult to work with. I was mostly getting errors about Python failing to initiate. So I exited that virtual environment and created a new one using python3-venv  (python3 -m venv venv). This new virtual environment is in /home/dj/venv/. I successfully linked the Python-home in the Apache site config (under sites-available) and Apache starts correctly. Upon connecting to the server, it serves the following page:

```
**Internal Server Error**
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

And the log holds the following:

```
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.078889 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873770018560] [remote 192.168.12.249:46870] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.269447 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872] mod_wsgi (pid=5687): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/dj/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py'.
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.269546 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872] mod_wsgi (pid=5687): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/dj/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py'.
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.269956 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270128 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]   File "/home/dj/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270144 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270169 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]   File "/home/dj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270184 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270209 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]   File "/home/dj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270239 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270263 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]   File "/home/dj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270278 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]     self._setup(name)
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270303 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]   File "/home/dj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270317 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270341 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]   File "/home/dj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270356 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270381 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270395 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270420 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270445 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270469 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270494 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270519 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270544 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270568 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Fri May 22 16:27:02.270613 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5687:tid 139873744815872] [remote 192.168.12.249:46872] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'
```

My site configuration (django_project.conf in Apache2/sites-available/) looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    Alias /static /home/dj/myproject/static/
    <Directory /home/dj/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    Alias /media /home/dj/myproject/media/
        <Directory /home/dj/myproject/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>


    <Directory /home/dj/myproject/myproject/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>


    WSGIDaemonProcess expandb.io python-home=/home/dj/venv/ python-path=/home/dj/myproject/myproject/
    WSGIProcessGroup expandbio
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/dj/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py process-group=expandb.io




</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I cannot see how to get the 'myproject' module into the Python environment, other than what I have already done.

Thank you. First post as well.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the issue. Here it is for anyone else facing something similar:

The virtual environment was located in the user's home directory. The Apache user didn't have access to this. I moved it to /usr/local/django

I then changed the 'python-home' location in the Apache configuration for this site under sites-enabled (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/.conf) and set it to the new virtual environment folder.

Also ensure that the 'python-path' is set to the root directory of your project, not the inner directory of the same name.